# Node: How can I filter on a JSON value that is nested within multiple arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, filter, nested

I am pulling data from an API that looks like this:

```js
[{
    id: "62ff4289163f2d1ec1d54ff16bd8d731",
    sport_key: "americanfootball_ncaaf",
    commence_time: "2021-08-28T17:00:00Z",
    home_team: "Illinois Fighting Illini",
    away_team: "Nebraska Cornhuskers",
    bookmakers: [{
        key: "unibet",
        title: "Unibet",
        last_update: "2021-07-16T23:33:36Z",
        markets: [{
          key: "spreads",
          outcomes: [{
              name: "Illinois Fighting Illini",
              price: 1.89,
              point: 8
            },
            {
              name: "Nebraska Cornhuskers",
              price: 1.89,
              point: -8
            }
          ]
        }]
      },
      {
        key: "barstool",
        title: "Barstool Sportsbook",
        last_update: "2021-07-16T23:28:36Z",
        markets: [{
          key: "spreads",
          outcomes: [{
              name: "Illinois Fighting Illini",
              price: 1.91,
              point: 8
            },
            {
              name: "Nebraska Cornhuskers",
              price: 1.91,
              point: -8
            }
          ]
        }]
      }
    ]
```

The relevant section of my code looks like this (the (data) is the JSON posted above):

```
response.on("end", () => {
        const oddsData = JSON.parse(data);
        let games = oddsData.length;
        for(let i=0; i<games; i++){
            let bookies = oddsData[i].bookmakers.length;
            for(let b=0; b<bookies; b++){
                        console.log(oddsData[i].bookmakers[b]);
        }
    }
})
```

How can I filter to only show results for the bookmaker with the key "barstool"? I have been googling different array filters and reduce functions all week and I cannot get this figured out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have an array which is containing first level objects and inside the first level objects you have bookmakers array which is an array of objects.

if you are looking to filter the bookmarks array, which is what I think what you should be looking for

```
dataArr.forEach(item => {
       item.bookmakers = item.bookmakers.filter(bookmaker => bookmaker.key == "barstool")
})
```

if you are looking to filter the array containing first level objects, you can do something like below

```
dataArr = dataArr.filter(item => {
    let keep = false;
    item.bookmakers.forEach(bookmaker => {
        if(bookmaker.key == "barstool"){
            keep = true;
        }
    })
    return keep;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess something like that:

```
gamesWithBarstool = oddsData.filter(game => game.bookmakers.some(bookmaker => bookmaker.key === 'barstool'))
```

With that you should only get the list of games that have odds for your named bookmaker.

**filter**:
Will return the subset of the array that matches the test.

**some**:
Will return true if any item in the array matches the test.